# GitHub add users to work together on repo...?

Tags: git, repository

After searching numerous days I'm just going to ask that We are with 5 persons and  we're going to develop 2 projects. One project is a JSP website (made in Netbeans) and one is a WPF end application made with C# and developed in Visual Studio 2010.

The idea was basically, making 2 repository's on GitHub and add the other 4 persons to these repositories. But, how do I add them and let them work together on these projects?

Currently I have Git Gui working perfectly with my repository and it can pull and push the files, but with the other guys it isn't. Can you help us please?

Answer (score 10):

A little bit late, but in the repository, go to settings, then look for collaborators, and then add the other persons working on the project.

Comment: I guess this answer is outdated - there are no "collaborators" option in the "settings". There is "Manage Access" - you can invite other users in there.

Answer (score 6):

If you own the repository with your personal GitHub account:
Add the other github users as collaborators (repo->settings->collaborators), then they have push access and will be able to work with you.

If the repo is owned by an organisation (I assume you are a manager of the organisation):
Make a team and manage who can push to projects like that (repo->settings->teams). You control access per-team, so you define a team that can pull, or push and pull, then add the users to it.

Comment: Nevermind, we sorted it out using a other method (Netbeans and Java.net) and later on Team Foundation Server with Codeplex.com.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 (ten years later), you would define (on GitHub) **Entitlements**.

> ### [Introducing Entitlements: GitHub’s open source Identity and Access Management solution](https://github.blog/2022-06-09-introducing-entitlements-githubs-open-source-identity-and-access-management-solution/)

Based on [`github/entitlements-app`](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app)

> `entitlements-app` is a Ruby gem which provides git-managed LDAP group configuration and access provisioning to your declared resources.
>
> It powers Entitlements, GitHub's internal Identity and Access Management (IAM) system. Entitlements is a pluggable system designed to alleviate IAM pain points.

You can [define your LDAP organization](https://github.com/github/entitlements-config/blob/91d3b297c3c0eda570dbf4478e7d779c0116637a/config/entitlements.yaml), and [define your teams and team member in a config file](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app/blob/6dd2a36a1c8921b719e12a8f74ed6251b20fea5b/docs/configuration.md).

> ### [Git-managed config](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app/tree/6dd2a36a1c8921b719e12a8f74ed6251b20fea5b#git-managed-config=)
>
> Entitlements receives input from configuration files. By using git to back the config files, every file has a complete and visible audit trail.
>
> See [configuration](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app/blob/6dd2a36a1c8921b719e12a8f74ed6251b20fea5b/docs/configuration.md) for a complete guide on entitlements configuration.
> Populating config from a source of truth
>
> Entitlements requires an initial Org Chart configuration to define all of the valid users available to the system.
>
> See [orgchart](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app/blob/6dd2a36a1c8921b719e12a8f74ed6251b20fea5b/docs/orgchart.md) for a complete guide to configuring your org chart data.
>
> To take advantage of the full entitlements re-organization functionality, your org chart data should be automatically updated as changes happen to your organization.
>
> See [reorgs](https://github.com/github/entitlements-app/blob/6dd2a36a1c8921b719e12a8f74ed6251b20fea5b/docs/reorgs.md) for examples of how Entitlements helps with re-orgs.