# GitHub: how do I make a user an admin of an organization?

Tags: github, github-organizations

I need to [transfer a repository from a user account to an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository) the user is a member of. Per GitHUb's docs,  I need to make the user account an admin of the organization first.

GitHub's docs describe [the different levels of access to an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions), but I **can't find out how to actually change a user's level of access to an organisation**.

How can I make the organization member an admin?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Access levels in GitHub are configured per Team inside the Organization.

1. Log into GitHub.
2. Switch your account context to the organization using the dropdown near the top-left of the screen:

   [image: User / organization dropdown]
3. Click on "View organization":

   [image: "View organization" button]
4. Click the Teams tab in the top navigation bar:

   [image: "Teams" button in the top navigation]
5. Decide whether you want to change the permissions of an existing team (and all of its members) or to create a new team for a single user.

   - If you are modifying an existing Team,

     1. click on the Team name,
     2. then click the gear icon at the top right,
     3. then change the Team's access to Admin and
     4. click Update.
   - If you are creating a new Team,

     1. click the New Team button,
     2. give the Team an appropriate name,
     3. set its access to Admin and
     4. click Create Team.

Comment: I don't think Teams are available for a free account, are they?

Comment: Is this still accurate?  As of Mar. 22, 2023, I don't see anything in Team Settings that let's me change or even assign "access".  I just see Team name, Description, Parent team and Team visibility.

Answer (score 13):

Team memberships have somewhat limited permissions scopes to individually named repositories.

If you want to set someone as an admin for the **entire organization**:

1. Navigate to the Organization > People

   [image: org > people]
2. Identify the member you want to update and click on the settings cog

   [image: settings > change role]
3. Set role to `Owner`

   [image: Select Role]

Answer (score 7):

Update 2022: **[GitHub entitlements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72565972/6309)** can help you define an IAM (Identity and Access Management) complete with audits.

---

2017:  Note that since June 2017, you can apply an Admin access right to a *sub*-team (instead of one giant unique team as before)

See "[Nested teams add depth to your team structure](https://github.com/blog/2378-nested-teams-add-depth-to-your-team-structure)":

[image: nested teams]

> Child teams inherit their parent's access permissions, so repository permissions and `@mentioning` among nested teams work from top to bottom.
> If your team structure is `Employees > Engineering > Application Engineering > Identity`, granting `Engineering` write access to a repository means `Application Engineering` and `Identity` also get that access.

So that is another way to assign a user admin right: make him/her part of a sub-sub team called "admins" within an organization.

Official GitHub Documentation: [**Nested Teams**](https://help.github.com/articles/about-teams/#nested-teams).