# Overwrite default repository permission on Github

Tags: github, permissions

I've set the default repository permission to "Read" at the organisation level. I can see how to widen permissions for a single repository. However I can't see how to restrict it.

Is it possible to restrict default permissions at repository level?

Answer (score 1):

Considering "[Repository permission levels for an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/)", "Read" seems to be already the most restrictive permission level.

It would therefore be logical to not be able to restrict a repository permission any further.

> There are three types of repository permissions available for people or teams collaborating on repositories that belong to an organization:
>
> - Read
> - Write
> - Admin
>
> In addition, organization members with owner permissions have extensive permissions across all repositories in an organization.

Check if you are the repository owner: if that is the case, there are other Repository settings you can modify, including:

> - Adding, removing, and editing collaborator access
> - Editing the repository's default branch
> - Adding, removing, and editing webhooks and service hooks
> - Adding deploy keys
> - Changing repository visibility (from [public to private](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private), or from [private to public](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-private-repository-public))

The last one is a way to restrict perhaps.

---

Note: (June 2017) check if the possibility to associate permission to **[nested teams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530200/6309)** can help.

Comment: No visibility would be even more restrictive than “Read”, no? I've got my org’s default member permissions to read visibility on all projects, but on a few repos I need something more restrictive, such that only certain teams can even see the projects. Is this possible?

Comment: @JustinMakeig reading https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/, you might be able to define teams and assign repos to them.